# "По этому поводу" or "по поводу этого"

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова

I recently came across the sentence: **Не беспокойся по поводу этого** and wondered if it can also be expressed as **Не беспокойся по этому поводу** with no change in meaning.

Comment: Could you please provide some more context?

Comment: If both phrases are complete sentences, then the meaning is the same.

Comment: @Quassnoi: I guess any context where one would be concerned?

Answer (score 3):

По этому поводу and по поводу этого (not followed by a noun) are synonyms. According to the National Corpus the first is used more often.

> Василь Быков. Лесное счастье 
>   Правительство срочно определило праздничный день Идеи; общественный комитет, созданный **по этому поводу**, разработал целый комплекс торжественных мероприятий.
>
> Виктор Пелевин. Ника
>   Я не помню, когда она первый раз пошла гулять без меня, но помню свои чувства **по этому поводу** ― я отпустил её без особого волнения, отбросив вялую мысль о том, что надо бы пойти вместе.
>
> Володин Борис. «Мы собрались не смотреть, а рассмотреть медиумические явления...» 
>   **По поводу этого** г-н Аксаков заявил, что «это нехорошо».

The second phrase is more often used with a noun.

> А. Т. Твардовский. Рабочие тетради 60-х годов (1968) // «Знамя», 2003
>   А кроме того ― какая бы радость была **по поводу этого «ЧП»** в пятом подъезде (это, оказывается, агитпроп, а в отдел культуры еще будет особое наставление), какая возможность для «оформления дела».
>
> З. И. Воскресенская. Сердце матери (1963-1965)
>   **По поводу этого случая** я беседовал с матерью о...

Answer (score 2):

> По этому поводу

This means related to the discussed topic.

> По поводу этого

Related to the discussed event or situation.